# Setting a variable equal to a state updates the state on variable change

Tags: reactjs, state, var

I ultimately want to create a copy of the state, update it accordingly without re-render then setState(myCopy) to trigger the View update. This question is better explained through code:

```
export default function App() {
   // Table Data
  const [tableState, setTableState] = useState({
    tableHead: ['Currency', 'Sell', 'Buy'],
    tableData: [
      ['USD', '1', '1'],
      ['EUR', '2', '2'],
      ['JPY', '3', '3'],
    ],
  });
  var newTableState = tableState;

  useState(() => {
    let rate1 = 15;
    let rate2 = 8;

    // * These 2 lines:
    newTableState.tableData[0][1] = rate1;
    newTableState.tableData[0][2] = rate2;
  },[])

  return(
   <View>
    <Text>{tableState.tableData[0][1]}</Text>
    <Text>{tableState.tableData[0][2]}</Text>
   </View>
  )
}
```

The two lines should only update newTableState. However, tableState is also being updated which updates the View. Is this the expected behaviour ?

I remember reading that updating a state directly without using setState is bad practice which is being done here in my opinion.

Here's a [demonstrating snack](https://snack.expo.io/@usersina/smiling-graham-crackers).

Comment: If you want to copy the tableState and don't want to change the reference then you should do - `var newTableState = {...tableState};`

Comment: I think the reference is not being changed in my case, since the state updates without setState. Tried this and it had the same result. Should I worry about not using setState ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're not assigning the tableState itself but a reference to it. So updating `newTableState` means that you're mutating the state.

There are a couple of ways to do that, either by using `lodash`'s `cloneDeep`

```js
const newTableState = cloneDeep(tableState);
```

or by using `JSON` like this:

```js
const newTableState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tableState));
```

Comment: Is it harmful to update the state like I'm doing ? Or should I make a clone and edit it first ?

Comment: It actually is, if you mutate your state your component won't re-render.